# how to create GPS location widget using django?

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

i am newbie to web development in all aspects;
i've went through the bast tutorial of django and now i would like to construct something which can launch a map on html, let the user pick a location and return the (lang,lat) coordinates back to django;

any ideas of how generally this should be accomplished?
if you got a working example it would be even more nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's GeoDjango, which is Django with Geospatial capabilities - it uses a spatial database such as spatialite or PostGIS.

That will do for database management. For map presentation, use OpenLayers or some other open source javascript map framework.

Hopefully that's enough for you to do some research and find a solution. If you've got more specific questions, ask them either here or more likely on the gis.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: is the GeoDjango a live project? i wasn't sure about this.

Comment: GeoDjango is part of core Django, so continues to be supported as long as the main project is.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried http://djangosnippets.org ?

Google Geocode Lookup: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/293/
Get Latitude and Longitude from google maps: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/483/

Comment: +1 GeoDjango is maybe a bit heavy duty for the sramij's requirements. I would recommend trying one of these snippets.